# Why can't I access my samba shares with this simple configuration? (CentOS 6)

Tags: centos, samba

On a freshly installed CentOS 6 system I have the following simple smb.conf copied from another system where it is working as expected:

```
workgroup = MYDOMAIN
browseable = yes
[homes]
guest ok = no
read only = no
[tmp]
path = /tmp
read only = no
guest ok = yes
[backups]
path = /backups
read only = no
guest ok = no
```

I have disabled SELinux and allowed the Samba ports through on the firewall.  I have set `joe`'s samba password with `smbpasswd -a joe`.  `/home/joe` and `/home` have 755 permissions and `/home/joe` has user/group `joe`.  `/backups` has user/group root and 777 permissions.

This should allow a user `joe` with permission to access /backups to connect to read/write  \hostname\backups on Windows or via the samba client on the same Linux host.  It should also allow access to \hostname\joe (home directory) given that `joe` can access his home directory `/home/joe`.

Using the Linux client on the local host:

```
$ smbclient --user joe '\\hostname\joe'
Enter joe's password: 
Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*

        62359 blocks of size 33553920. 59182 blocks available
smb: \> cd Documents
smb: \Documents\> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \Documents\*

        62359 blocks of size 33553920. 59182 blocks available
smb: \Documents\>
```

So here I can connect to the share but can't see the contents, yet can cd to a directory I know is there.  Note that `/home/joe/Documents` is also 755 and owned by `joe`.

Now I'll try to access `backups`:

```
$ smbclient --user joe '\\hostname\backups\'
Enter joe's password: 
Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

So in this case I can't even connect to the share at all.  Further, I see from `tail -f /var/log/samba/log.smbd`:

```
[2013/02/22 11:09:49.734263,  0] smbd/service.c:988(make_connection_snum) 
canonicalize_connect_path failed for service backups, path /backups
```

This message doesn't appear in the case where I'm connectng to my home share.  `/backups` definitely exists, has mode 777, and is the mountpoint for an external RAID device which is working fine.

I have another system with essentially identical configuration except that it's CentOS 5 and Samba 3.0.33 instead of 3.5.10.  Everything works as expected there.

On Windows, trying to access either `\\hostname\backups` or `\\hostname\joe` (with the right credentials of course) gives an unhelpful 'you do not have permissions... ' dialog with "Details": 'The network name could not be found'.

Please help me get to the bottom of this!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to step with iptables. Try this:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s adreess -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s address -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s address -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s address -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
```

pd: excuse my english, I'm using Google Translator.

Comment: Thanks but it's not a firewall issue; I turned off iptables completely and it made no difference to the symptoms.